# 'does not appear to be an NgModule class.' error after updating to Angular@15

Tags: angular-cli

I'm trying to update from `Angular@13` to `Angular@15`. After doing so, I'm getting compile error that I completely don't understand.

```
 'SharedModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
  src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:127:14
    127 export class SharedModule {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
```

It is module that I use in a whole project that has other modules imported.
Here is code with that module. `@NgModule` annotation is there.

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {FontAwesomeModule} from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';


import {TooltipsModule} from '@lukana/tooltips';
import {DropdownsModule} from '@lukana/dropdowns';

import {SchematerModule} from '@schemater/core';
import {SchematerComponentsModule} from '@schemater/components';
import {SchematerFilterBarModule} from '@schemater/filter-bar';
import {DropdownComponent} from './components/dropdown/dropdown.component';
import {BlankPageComponent} from '@app/shared/pages/blank-page/blank-page.component';
import {PageEmptyRouterOutletComponent} from '@app/shared/pages/page-empty-router-outlet/page-empty-router-outlet.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {StickyDirective} from './components/sticky/sticky.directive';
import {LoadingIndicatorModule} from '@lukana/loading-indicator';
import {NgSelectModule} from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import {A11yModule} from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import {FormularzeModule} from '@app/utils/formularze/formularze.module';
import {UprawnieniaSharedModule} from '@app/administrator/uprawnienia/uprawnienia-shared/uprawnienia-shared.module';
import {PokazUkryjModule} from '@app/utils/pokaz-ukryj/pokaz-ukryj.module';
import {IkonkiModule} from '@app/shared/ikonki/ikonki.module';
import {ClickStopPropagationDirective} from './components/click-stop-propagation.directive';
import {DostosowanieSharedModule} from '@app/dostosowanie/dostosowanie-shared/dostosowanie-shared.module';
import {ListyModule} from '@app/shared/listy/listy.module';
import {ContainerResizeObserverModule} from '@app/utils/container-resize-observer/container-resize-observer.module';
import {IkonkaRozwijaniaModule} from '@app/utils/ikonka-rozwijania/ikonka-rozwijania.module';
import {ModulySharedModule} from '@app/moduly/moduly-shared/moduly-shared.module';
// import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

// defineLocale('pl', plLocale);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,

    A11yModule,
    // BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    // SortablejsModule.forRoot({animation: 150}),
    // DragDropModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    ModulySharedModule,

    TooltipsModule,
    DropdownsModule,
    LoadingIndicatorModule.forRoot({}),
    SchematerModule,
    SchematerComponentsModule,
    SchematerFilterBarModule,

    UprawnieniaSharedModule,
    IkonkiModule,

    FormularzeModule,
    PokazUkryjModule,

    DostosowanieSharedModule,
    ListyModule,
    ContainerResizeObserverModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    // pages
    BlankPageComponent,
    PageEmptyRouterOutletComponent,
    // components
    DropdownComponent,
    StickyDirective,
    ClickStopPropagationDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    UprawnieniaSharedModule,
    ModulySharedModule,

    A11yModule,

    FontAwesomeModule,
    // BsDatepickerModule,
    // SortablejsModule,
    // DragDropModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    TooltipsModule,
    DropdownsModule,
    LoadingIndicatorModule,
    SchematerModule,
    SchematerComponentsModule,
    SchematerFilterBarModule,

    IkonkiModule,
    FormularzeModule,
    PokazUkryjModule,
    // pages
    BlankPageComponent,
    PageEmptyRouterOutletComponent,

    // components
    DropdownComponent,
    StickyDirective,
    ClickStopPropagationDirective,

    DostosowanieSharedModule,
    ListyModule,
    ContainerResizeObserverModule,
  ],
  // providers: [
  //   {
  //     provide: NG_SELECT_DEFAULT_CONFIG,
  //     useValue: {
  //       placeholder: '',
  //       notFoundText: 'Nic nie znalazłem',
  //       typeToSearchText: 'Wpisz by wyszukać',
  //       addTagText: 'Dodaj tag',
  //       loadingText: 'Wgrywam',
  //       clearAllText: 'Wyczyść wszystko',
  //     }
  //   }
  // ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

EDIT:

I've noticed that this import is responsible for not finding @NgModule annotation error:
`LoadingIndicatorModule.forRoot({}),`
I cannot get why.
Here is source code for `LoadingIndicatorModule`

```js
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LoadingOverlayDirective} from './loading-overlay.directive';
import {LoadingBarDirective} from './loading-bar.directive';
import {LukanaLoadingModuleConfig} from './models/lukana-loading-module-config';
import {CONFIG} from './configToken';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [LoadingOverlayDirective, LoadingBarDirective],
  exports: [LoadingOverlayDirective, LoadingBarDirective]
})
export class LoadingIndicatorModule {
  static forRoot(config?: LukanaLoadingModuleConfig): ModuleWithProviders<any> {
    // console.log(config);
    return {
      ngModule: LoadingIndicatorModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CONFIG,
          useValue: config
        },
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution to fix this issue? I am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading angular try running ngcc. you can add ngcc as postinstall in package.json and run it.